# Grouping Data in a List/Hashmap

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I am having a file like this

```
Petal_Length    0   1.3 - 2.42
Petal_Length    1   2.42 - 3.54
Petal_Length    2   3.54 - 4.66
Petal_Length    3   4.66 - 5.78
Petal_Length    4   5.78 - 6.9
Petal_Width     5   0.3 - 0.76
Petal_Width     6   0.76 - 1.2200000000000002
Petal_Width     7   1.2200000000000002 - 1.6800000000000002
Petal_Width     8   1.6800000000000002 - 2.14
Petal_Width     9   2.14 - 2.6
Sepal_Length    10  4.3 - 5.02
Sepal_Length    11  5.02 - 5.739999999999999
Sepal_Length    12  5.739999999999999 - 6.459999999999999
Sepal_Length    13  6.459999999999999 - 7.179999999999999
Sepal_Length    14  7.179999999999999 - 7.899999999999999
Sepal_Width     15  2.3 - 2.76
Sepal_Width     16  2.76 - 3.2199999999999998
Sepal_Width     17  3.2199999999999998 - 3.6799999999999997
Sepal_Width     18  3.6799999999999997 - 4.14
Sepal_Width     19  4.14 - 4.6
```

I am trying to group these data as

```
Petal_Length[0:1.3 - 2.42,1:2.42 - 3.54,2:3.54 - 4.66,3:4.66 - 5.78,4:5.78 - 6.9]
```

Is that the way of grouping .
My aim is to get the attribute name index and the range.

Whether to use hashmap?

**UPDATE**

What I did is -

```
       while((line = bf.readLine())!=null){
        String featureVal[] = line.split("\t");
        val.add(featureVal[0]);
        listToSet = new HashSet<String>(val);
        //Creating Arraylist without duplicate values
        attributeVal = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet);
        //Extracting key
        binMap.put(featureVal[0], new ArrayList<String>());
        //Extracting Values
        String[] cols = featureVal[1].split("\t");
        for(int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
            if(attributeVal.get(i).equals(cols[i])){
                System.out.println("in foorlop");
                List<String> tmpList = binMap.get(attributeVal.get(i));
                if(tmpList == null) {
                    tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                System.out.println("cols[i]"+cols[i]);
                tmpList.add(cols[i]);
                //Get the list and add to that list instead of creating new temp list
                binMap.put(attributeVal.get(i), tmpList);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("binMap: "+binMap);

    }
```

But my output is null

```
binMap: {Petal_Width=[], Sepal_Length=[], Petal_Length=[], Sepal_Width=[]}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code for you, please note how there are domain classes like Range and Attribute are used for string parsing convenience. All the grouping is done via regular java map.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class PetalGrouping {
    private static final String input = "Petal_Length\t0\t1.3 - 2.42\n"
        + "Petal_Length\t1\t2.42 - 3.54\n"
        + "Petal_Length\t2\t3.54 - 4.66\n"
        + "Petal_Length\t3\t4.66 - 5.78\n"
        + "Petal_Length\t4\t5.78 - 6.9\n"
        + "Petal_Width\t 5\t0.3 - 0.76\n"
        + "Petal_Width\t 6\t0.76 - 1.2200000000000002\n"
        + "Petal_Width\t 7\t1.2200000000000002 - 1.6800000000000002\n"
        + "Petal_Width\t 8\t1.6800000000000002 - 2.14\n"
        + "Petal_Width\t 9\t2.14 - 2.6\n"
        + "Sepal_Length\t10\t4.3 - 5.02\n"
        + "Sepal_Length\t11\t5.02 - 5.739999999999999\n"
        + "Sepal_Length\t12\t5.739999999999999 - 6.459999999999999\n"
        + "Sepal_Length\t13\t6.459999999999999 - 7.179999999999999\n"
        + "Sepal_Length\t14\t7.179999999999999 - 7.899999999999999\n"
        + "Sepal_Width\t 15\t2.3 - 2.76\n"
        + "Sepal_Width\t 16\t2.76 - 3.2199999999999998\n"
        + "Sepal_Width\t 17\t3.2199999999999998 - 3.6799999999999997\n"
        + "Sepal_Width\t 18\t3.6799999999999997 - 4.14\n"
        + "Sepal_Width\t 19\t4.14 - 4.6";

public static void main(String... args) {
    Map<String, List<Attribute>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Attribute>>();
    String[] lines = input.split("\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        Attribute attribute = Attribute.parse(line);
        List<Attribute> attributeList = map.get(attribute.getName());
        if (attributeList == null) {
            attributeList = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
            map.put(attribute.getName(), attributeList);
        }
        attributeList.add(attribute);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}


}

class Range {
private double from;
private double to;

private Range(double from, double to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
}

public static Range parse(String string) {
    String[] parts = string.split(" ");
    if (parts.length != 3) { throw new RuntimeException("Parsing failed for line: " + string); }
    return new Range(Double.parseDouble(parts[0].trim()), Double.parseDouble(parts[2].trim()));
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{from=" + from + ", to=" + to + '}';
}
}

class Attribute {
private String name;
private int index;
private Range range;

protected Attribute(String name, int index, Range range) {
    this.name = name;
    this.index = index;
    this.range = range;
}

public static Attribute parse(String line) {
    String[] lineParts = line.split("\t");
    if (lineParts.length != 3) { throw new RuntimeException("Parsing failed for line: " + line); }
    String name = lineParts[0].trim();
    int index = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[1].trim());
    Range range = Range.parse(lineParts[2].trim());
    return new Attribute(name, index, range);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "index=" + index + " " + range + '}';
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}
```

Comment: Yes I did the same thing. But I am getting duplicate values in my key.

Comment: Not sure what it means - "duplicate values in my key" It would help if you post input data that giving you grief and results that you get/want to get

Comment: Map<String, List<Attribute>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Attribute>>(); how to iterate through the map.pairs.getKey() helps me to get the key and pairs.getValues() with the entire value.But i need individual value how to get it

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use JSON object or Custom Java Object like:

```
Class Flower{
  List<String> Petal_length;
  List<String> Petal_Width;
  List<String> Sepal_length;
  List<String> Sepal_Width;

}
```

If you want say, range of petal length, at 0 index then, we can do some thing like
String range = flower.Petal_length.get(0)

With Object it is more flexible, if later you get new file or you plan to add new attribute